# php substr() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, string

Hi i am trying to get the List of columns from a specific table in mysql and then generate a form based on the columns but i keep getting an error and the page is just blank.

```
mysql_select_db($DB_Name) or die(mysql_error());
$query=mysql_query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM mytable") or die (mysql_error());
$j=0;

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
    if(substr($row,0,2)=="S_"){
        echo substr($row,2);?>:<input type="text" name="<?php echo $row;?>" maxlength="<?php echo getlength($j, "mytable");?>" /><?php ?><!--textbox code here --><?php
    }
    $j++;
}
```

`getlength();` is a method i wrote to make it easier to get the `length of a field` for a column. It works accurately.

thanks

i think i didnt mention. Since the site is dynamic the name of the column isnt known. The point of this is to get the list of column names from a specific table and display it in an orderly manner.

Comment: using `substr` you can restrict the count of string values,not an array...

Comment: Who keeps decreasing my reputation? I did my research first and tried to be clear.

Comment: Sorry. Don't know about the reduction of reputation rates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_fetch_assoc returns an associative array. In this case you very likely are getting an array what kind of looks like this:

```
[FIELD] => "Name of the field",
 [Type] => "varchar(32)",
 [Null] => YES,
 [Key] => PRI,
 [Default] => '',
 [Extra] => ''
```

So, if you want to check the field name for S_ then you need to change your substr line to

```
substr($row['FIELD'], 0, 2)
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call `substr()`, you're currently passing in `$row`, which is an array.  You need to specify an index in the `$row` in order to return a particular element like this:

```
 $row['name']
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the column you wanted to trace. Here is the correct script below:

```
<?php
    if(substr($row['some_column'],0,2)=="S_"){
        echo substr($row['some_column'],2);

    }
?>
```

Hope that this help you.

Comment: not possible, the column will be added/removed/changed sometimes. The form generated is dynamic that means whichever column is in the table is used as a basis to generate the form and also for validating user input.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(substr($row,0,2)=="S_"){
    echo substr($row,2);?>
```

with

```
 if(substr($row['FIELD'],0,2)=="S_"){
    echo substr($row['FIELD'],2);?>
```

Comment: i get undefined index instead